# Laravel JWT authentication set the token expiration to 1 day

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I have API Laravel project and I am using JWT authentication and in the `respondWithToken()` I changed `getTTL() * 60` to `getTTL() * 1440` and it still return `401 Unauthorized` error after about 1 hour

And this is the controller functions

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);

    if (!$token = auth()->guard('admin_api')->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    $response = [];

    array_push($response, $this->respondWithToken($token), $this->me());

    return response()->json($response);
}

/**
 * Get the authenticated User.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */

public function me()
{
    return response()->json(auth('admin_api')->user());
}

/**
 * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */

public function logout()
{
    auth('admin_api')->logout();

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully Logged Out']);
}

/**
 * Refresh a token.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */

public function refresh()
{
    return $this->respondWithToken(auth('admin_api')->refresh());
}

/**
 * Get the token array structure.
 *
 * @param  string $token
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */

public function respondWithToken($token)
{
    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $token,
        'token_type' => 'bearer',
        'expires_in' => auth()->guard('admin_api')->factory()->getTTL() * 1440
    ]);
}

public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|string|between:2,100',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:100|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors()->toJson(), 400);
    }

    $user = User::create(
        array_merge(
            $validator->validated(),
            ['password' => bcrypt($request->password)]
        )
    );

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Admin Registered Successfully',
        'admin' => $user
    ], 201);
}
```

Can anyone help me recognize how to fix this issue?

Comment: JWTs are not supposed to be long-lived. The longer the expiration, the less secure your system is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using jwt configuration file:

1. [Publish config file](https://laravel-jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/laravel-installation/#publish-the-config)(if not already)

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
```

2. Set `JWT_TTL` in minutes in your **.env** file

```
JWT_TTL=1440 #set expiration to 1 day
```

3. read expiration time from config file

```
protected function respondWithToken(string $token): JsonResponse
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => config('jwt.ttl') * 60,
        ]);
    }
```